# Strange fdisk output for USB device

Tags: raspbian, usb, partition

I am trying to access a USB thumb drive.

The drive has been formatted using Windows 10's format utility. Nothing fancy: One (empty) FAT32 partition (named "VOLUME") taking up the drive's entire capacity (1GB). I verified that the thumb drive is working by running h2testw (under Windows) which reported no drive errors.

I am now trying to reformat the device to ext3 as I will only use it from the Raspbery Pi. I am following [this guide](http://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/17699796-formatting-and-mounting-a-usb-drive-from-a-terminal-window).

However, `fdisk` is showing me really strange output for the device (see picture):

[image]

This looks like complete garbage to me.

What's going on there?
Can I simply ignore this issue, delete the partitions and start over?

Comment: You seem to access the partition , not the block device itself :
/dev/sd1a vs /dev/sda

Comment: @flakeshake That is correct if you want to write a quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the partition, not the block device itself :
/dev/**sda1** vs /dev/**sda**.

Try using
`sudo fdisk /dev/sda`

Comment: Thanks - that works! Just out of curiosity: What is the reason for the strange output observed in the screenshot? Is that the result of fdisk trying to interpret partition content as another partition table?